# Code returning email type properties from untested item types stops at 26 items (out of 1200)

Tags: vba, outlook, export-to-pdf

Objective: Save emails as PDF files in a folder
Problem: Outlook folder has over 1000 emails. Code runs for 26 emails then stops/freezes.
Attempts: Tried different Outlook email folders with different content all stop at 26/27.

I suspect it is creating some type of memory issue.  Not closing something?

```vb
Sub save_as_PDF()
 
    Dim objDoc As Object, objInspector As Object
    Dim outApp As Object, objOutlook As Object, objFolder As Object, myItems As Object, myItem As Object
    Dim FolderPath, FileName, ClientName, ModTime, ranDigits As String

    Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objOutlook = outApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objFolder = objOutlook.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("regular")
    Set myItems = objFolder.Items

    FolderPath = "C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\My Documents\__AA My Daily\vbaOutlookTestFolder\"

    On Error Resume Next

    For Each myItem In myItems

        Set objInspector = Nothing
        Set objDoc = Nothing
        Set objInspector = Nothing
        Set objDoc = Nothing
        
        FileName = myItem.To
        FileName = Replace(FileName, ".", "")
        
        Set objInspector = myItem.GetInspector
        Set objDoc = objInspector.WordEditor
        
        objDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat FolderPath & FileName & ".pdf", 17

    Next myItem
    
End Sub
```

I expected it to convert every email item in the folder to a pdf.

Comment: **Remove**, do not comment out, `On Error Resume Next`. Learn when to use or stop using it. Update the post with any error messages.

Comment: OK will Remove and update any error messages

Comment: Does it work if you comment out Inspector and WordEditor lines and just call myItem.SaveAs(..., olTxt)?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related to the following line of code:

```
objDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat FolderPath & FileName & ".pdf", 17
```

The `FileName` is not unique and can remain the same for most of the items in the folder.

```
FileName = myItem.To
```

Instead, you need to generate a unique filename to avoid any troubles with saving pdf files. And try to add any ID to the string to avoid duplicates in the same folder.

Moreover, the file name may contain forbidden symbols:

```
  FileName = myItem.To
  FileName = Replace(FileName, ".", "")
```

Use the following function to remove any illegal characters from the file name string:

```
Function ReplaceIllegalCharacters(strIn As String, strChar As String) As String
    Dim strSpecialChars As String
    Dim i As Long
    strSpecialChars = "~""#%&*:<>?{|}/\[]" & Chr(10) & Chr(13)

    For i = 1 To Len(strSpecialChars)
        strIn = Replace(strIn , Mid$(strSpecialChars, i, 1), strChar)
    Next

    ReplaceIllegalCharacters = strIn 
End Function
```

A similar issue was described in the [pdf files not saving with ExportAsFixedFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69185515/pdf-files-not-saving-with-exportasfixedformat) thread.

Answer (score 1):

`myItem.To` can contain (in case of multiple To recipients) `";"`, which is invalid in file names.

Never use `On Error Resume Next` unless you actually check `Err.Number` - it'll just mask the exception and you don't know what hits you.